# Looking for ERP or CRM software for web design / marketing agency

Tags: crm, enterprise-portal

I'm looking for some business software to make my life a bit easier. I run a small but growing web design / marketing firm in Connecticut. One of the biggest problems I'm facing is that now my data is starting to get spread across multiple applications.

I'd like software to do the following:

- CRM
- Proposals
- Google integration
- email marketing
- invoicing / online payments
- custom work flows
- cloud based

I've seen several applications that usually offer part of these items but never all in one.

Being a fairly competent programmer I'm willing to do some API integrations if necessary. However the idea is to find something so my data is spread across AS FEW applications as possible

Any recommendations would be wonderful!

Comment: "Google integration": What exactly do you want to achieve this that? Google has so many different services.

Comment: Do you need document management too? You wrote "cloud based", does that mean you want everything be hosted online?

Comment: Document integration would be a great feature. We've thought about using Google but from what I've seen the user interface between apps is the really great. Unless you can suggest otherwise. We're all open to any suggestions!

Comment: Sorry... to clarify what I meant by Google integration is the email, contacts and calendar. Google is great with this kind d of stuff but I'd like it to have a deep integration with a CRM.

Comment: Could you please include that into the body of your question, to make the Google integration bullet clearer?

Answer (score 2):

Significantly more affordable than Salesforce, and offering good integration with Google, you can check out Zoho CRM. Here is a high level list of features:

```
Prioritize sales activities
Visitor tracking
Zoho CRM for Google AdWords

Sales force automation
Lead management
Contact management
Account management
Sales collateral
Web forms
Workflow automation
Marketing automation

Sales tracking
Opportunity management
Role-based security
Sales reports and dashboards
Advanced CRM analytics
Sales tracking

Sales performance management
Gamification
Territory management
Sales forecasting

Engage
Social CRM
PhoneBridge
Email

Extend CRM
Customization
Custom apps
Custom functions
Developer API

Go Mobile
iOS and Android apps
Leads app
Card Scanner app
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not be inexpensive, but Salesforce, with add-on apps has all these features. It's designed to do exactly what you want. You can try googling alternatives to Salesforce and you'll get lots of options.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your criterial correctly, I’d say that you need a CRM system that would be efficient in 2 areas: marketing and sales automation. Bpm’online marketing https://www.bpmonline.com/marketing takes care of all your marketing campaigns. And one thing it excels at is personalized email marketing. Having a 360-degree overview on each of your contacts at your disposal, you can reach everyone on your target audience individually. And your marketing campaigns will finally start to pay off. You can integrate all your email boxes in one environment, not to mention the integration with Google and MS Exchange. You’ll be able to keep all of your customer data stored in one place. Bpm’online sales https://www.bpmonline.com/sales will take care the rest of the list. Both of these products are seamlessly integrated with one another on a single platform so, it will definitely make your life easier. You will be able to have total control of a complete customer journey with little to no effort. As your business grows, you will be able to adjust the automation of the business processes to match the rising business needs and objectives.

Comment: Are you affiliated with the software / bpmonline.com? If yes, please [edit] your answer (and your other two answers recommending the same solution) and disclose it.